# How to append results via concatenation or push method in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have tried most solution found on Stack Overflow but unfortunately they do not solve my issue.

The code works fine below by displaying data from an array. When I click on get New Price, a New Price is fetched via Axios Json Call and everything is okay.

Here is a sample of price.json data returned via Axios API call:

```
[{"category_id" : "101", "status":"1", "category_price":"900"}]
```

Now. here is what am trying to achieve. I want each time a user clicks on get new price, let the retrieved price gets appended to already existing results.

I knew this is a work of **push()** or **concat()** function.

I have tried:

```
const data=this.state.data.concat(response.data);
```

or:

```
const newData = this.state.data.concat.map(store => {
```

but it shows **concat.map error**.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false,
commenta: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [{
        "provision_id":"1",
        "provision":"Milk",
        "category":[{"category_id":"1", "category_price":"100 USD" }, {"category_id":"2", "category_price":"200 USD" },
{"category_id":"3", "category_price":"300 USD" }]

      }],
    });
  }

  // Get New Price of Milk and concatenate it
  handleNewPrice(pro_id) {
    alert(pro_id);
    const product = {
      pro_id: pro_id};
      axios
        .get("http://localhost/price.json", { product })
        .then(response => {

         /*commented below is what I have tried */
         //const data=this.state.data.concat(response.data);
         //const newData = this.state.data.concat.map(store => {

         const newData = this.state.data.map(store => {
            if (store.provision_id !== pro_id) return store;
            return {
               ..store, 
               category_new: [{
                   ...store.category_new,
                   category_price_new: response.data[0].category_price, 
                   category_id_new: response.data[0].category_id
               }]
           };

          /* Not applicable 
         return {
              ...store, 
              category_new: store.category.map(
              category => {
                  if (category.category_id !== pro_id) return category;
                  if (category.category_id === pro_id) {
                  return {  
                     ...store.category_new,
                     category_price_new: response.data[0].category_price,           
                     category_id_new: response.data[0].category_id 
                  }
             }
      }
    )
  }
*/
  
    });
    this.setState(state => ({
        data: newData
    }));
    console.log(response.data[0].category_price);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

    render() {
      return (
        <span>
          <label>
            <ul>
<h1>Provision Store</h1> <br />
              {this.state.data.map((store) => {
                return (
                  <div key={store.provision_id}>
                    <div>
                      <b> Product: </b>{store.provision} 
                    </div>

<br />




                    {store.category && store.category.map((cat) => {

                      return (
                        <div key={cat.category_id}>
                          <div>


<b>Prices:</b> {cat.category_price}
                            <br />
                            

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })}



 {store.category_new && store.category_new.map((cat1) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={cat1.category_id_new}>

                          <div><b>New Prices:</b> {cat1.category_price_new}  ----- {cat1.category_id_new}
                          
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })}

                            <input
                              type="button"
                              value="Get New Prices and Concatenate"
                              onClick={() => this.handleNewPrice(store.provision_id)}
                            />


                  </div>
                )
              }
            )}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

### Updated section of the code

I have tried all the three solutions provided by three Stack Overflow users, but only one seems to be partly working.

If I implement the code below via **Concat()** function and then click on **Get Price Button** for the first time, the New price will be displayed in **red**.

If then Click **Get Price Button** for the second time, third time and so on, instead of another New Price to display/append, it will replace/displace already existing new price in red.

```
const data= this.state.data;
data.concat([...response.data]);
```

[See screenshot for concat function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQcMb.png)

If I then implement the code below via **Push()** function and then click on **Get Price Button** for the first time, the new price
will be display in **red** along with one more unknown click button.

If then **Click Get Price** button for the second time, third time and so on, another New Price to display/append in red along with **three more Click Button** which I did not know where it's coming from.

```
const data= this.state.data;
data.push([...response.data]);
```

[see screenshot for push function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJrJK.png)

Below is the code so far:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false,
commenta: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [{
        "provision_id":"1",
        "provision":"Milk",
        "category":[{"category_id":"1", "category_price":"100 USD" }, {"category_id":"2", "category_price":"200 USD" },
{"category_id":"3", "category_price":"300 USD" }]

      }],
    });
  }

  // Get New Price of Milk and concatenate it
  handleNewPrice(pro_id) {
    alert(pro_id);
    const product = {
      pro_id: pro_id};
      axios
        .get("http://localhost/price.json", { product })
        .then(response => {

/* Concat function */

const data= this.state.data;
data.concat([...response.data]);

/* push function */

//const data= this.state.data;
//data.push([...response.data]);


const newData = this.state.data.map(store => {
            if (store.provision_id !== pro_id) return store;

return {
  ...store, 
  category_new: [{
    ...store.category_new,
category_price_new: response.data[0].category_price, 
category_id_new:    response.data[0].category_id
  }]
};

            });

        this.setState(state => ({data: newData}));

            console.log(response.data[0].category_price);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <span>
          <label>
            <ul>
<h1>Provision Store</h1> <br />
              {this.state.data.map((store) => {
                return (
                  <div key={store.provision_id}>
                    <div>
                      <b> Product: </b>{store.provision} 
                    </div>

<br />

                    {store.category && store.category.map((cat) => {

                      return (
                        <div key={cat.category_id}>
                          <div>


<b>Prices:</b> {cat.category_price}
                            <br />
                            

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })}



 {store.category_new && store.category_new.map((cat1) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={cat1.category_id_new}>

                          <div><b style={{color: 'red'}}>New Prices:</b> {cat1.category_price_new}  ----- (Price ID: {cat1.category_id_new})
                          
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })}

                            <input
                              type="button"
                              value="Get New Prices and Concatenate"
                              onClick={() => this.handleNewPrice(store.provision_id)}
                            />

                  </div>
                )
              }
            )}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

### Updated section 2

Initial data before API Hits as requested by Umair Farooq. Thanks Umair, please see the screenshot below. The first screenshot shows how data appears before API call:

[Screenshot Before API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJyre.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, we now have **2 products Milk and Sugar** which we will want to be getting new price to each and append the result on the View

The second screenshot shows how data appears after API call by clicking **Get New Price button**.

[Screenshot after API Call by clicking Get New Price button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOL9J.png)

As you can see in the second screenshot, I have click on the Get price button and new price appears, If I click it second time, I need to see more new price result. That is I need to be seeing more New Prices get appended each time the button is clicked based on each product.

My problem is that New Price gets appended only on the first click of button via API Call but on second or subsequent click
no further result is appended and that is where concat() or push() functions needs to be implemented.

You can run this AngularJS code and see how new prices gets appended each time button is clicked.

Here is **old_data.json** files

```
[
{"id":"1", "cat_price":"100 usd"},
{"id":"2", "cat_price":"200 usd"}
]
```

Here is **new_data.json** files

```
[{"id":"10", "cat_price":"900 usd--New"}]
```

Here is a little Angularjs code that show how new prices gets appended each time Get price button is clicked:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body >

        <div ng-app='myapp' ng-controller="priceCtrl">
            <div>
<input type='button' id='but_save' value='Get New Price and Append' ng-click="add()" >
</div>
            <div ng-repeat="pr in prices">
                
            {{pr.cat_price}}
                
              
                
           </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Script -->
        <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

        fetch.controller('priceCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

            // Get all records
            $http({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'http://localhost/old_data.json',
                data: {request_type:1},

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.prices = response.data;
            });

            // Add and get new record
            $scope.add = function(){

                var len = $scope.prices.length;
                $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/new_data.json',
                data: {},
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.prices.push(response.data[0]);
                });
            }

          
            
        }]);

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the updated code for ReactJs.

For Axios API return response sample:

```
[{"category_id" : "005", "status":"1", "category_price":"900 usd"}]
```

Main React code

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class Apps extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false,
commenta: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [{
        "provision_id":"1",
        "provision":"Milk",
        "category":[{"category_id":"1", "category_price":"100 USD" }, {"category_id":"2", "category_price":"200 USD" }]},

{
        "provision_id":"2",
        "provision":"Sugar",
        "category":[{"category_id":"3", "category_price":"150 USD" }, {"category_id":"4", "category_price":"300 USD" }]},



],
    });
  }


 // Get New Price of Milk and concatenate it
  handleNewPrice(pro_id) {
    alert(pro_id);
    const product = {
      pro_id: pro_id};
      axios
        .get("http://localhost/price.json", { product })
        .then(response => {

const data= this.state.data;
data.concat([...response.data]);


//const data= this.state.data;
//data.push([...response.data]);




const newData = this.state.data.map(store => {
            if (store.provision_id !== pro_id) return store;

return {
  ...store, 
  category_new: [{
    ...store.category_new,
category_price_new: response.data[0].category_price, 
category_id_new:    response.data[0].category_id
  }]
};

            });

        this.setState(state => ({data: newData}));

            console.log(response.data[0].category_price);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }



    render() {
      return (
        <span>
          <label>
            <ul>
<h1>Provision Store</h1> <br />
              {this.state.data.map((store) => {
                return (
                  <div key={store.provision_id}>
                    <div>
                      <b style={{color:'blue'}}> Product: {store.provision} </b>
                    </div>

<br />

                    {store.category && store.category.map((cat) => {

                      return (
                        <div key={cat.category_id}>
                          <div>


<b>Prices:</b> {cat.category_price}
                            <br />
                            

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })}



 {store.category_new && store.category_new.map((cat1) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={cat1.category_id_new}>

                          <div><b style={{color: 'red'}}>New Prices:</b> {cat1.category_price_new}  ----- (Price ID: {cat1.category_id_new})
                          
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })}

                            <input
                              type="button"
                              value="Get New Prices and Concatenate"
                              onClick={() => this.handleNewPrice(store.provision_id)}
                            />
<br />
                  </div>
                )
              }
            )}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will append the new values in `category_new` array, it will not update already available categories which are fetched first time. You can use following:

```
// value form the server. If only one value is coming from server why use array(for server guy)
const newCategory= [{"category_id" : "101", "status":"1", "category_price":"900"}]
const newData = data.map(val => {
  if(val.provision_id === newCategory[0].category_id) {
    return {
     ...val
     category_new: (val.category_new || []).concat(newCategory)// assuming newCategory is available and its the category you want to concat
    }
  }
 return val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for your contribution so far. please can you see the updated section of the code to see if you can help me further. Thanks

Comment: Please can you share following in details. What is your initial data before api hit? What data is received by api hit? What data should be after merging initial data and api hit data? Just this info.

Comment: Sir Umair, thanks for your response so far. The code has been broken down. please see my post  on  Updated Section 2: Initial data before API Hits as requested by Stackoverflow Engineer – Umair Farooq

Comment: Thanks @NancyMooree  for updating question. Can you please update section2 with what would be the data after merging with api. Please remove code, just share data you want before and after api call. Just only data nothing more

Comment: Sir Umair, Update Section 2 has been added, Screenshots has been added to show data before and after API Hit.  A little angularjs code that shows how it will works has also been added. Reactjs code also updated. Thanks

Comment: I have updated code which will update `category_new` on api hit. Please share code in codesandbox if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this

```
var newPriceobj = Object.assign({}, ...this.state.data); // This will create a fresh object //
var newPriceobjArray = Object.keys(newPriceobj).map(i => newPriceobj[i]);
newPriceobjArray.push(response.data);
this.setState({data:newPriceobjArray});
```

> **Note:** Don't mutate the State directly, it might lead unpredictable situations

**Change:**

```
this.state.data.concat(response.data);
```

**To:**

```
var newPriceobj = Object.assign({}, ...this.state.data);
```

then use `newPriceobj`.

Please check: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

Comment: Thanks Sir for your contribution so far. please can you see the updated section of the code to see if you can help me further. Thanks